# Why does The Punisher not disguise himself?

Tags: marvel, secret-identity, the-punisher

[image: The Punisher]

Unlike most super heroes, the police and the general public do not approve of The Punisher due to the fact that he kills his enemies. So my question is, why does he make himself so easily identifiable? He doesn't wear a mask or make any attempt to mask his face and he wears the same distinct logo on all his clothing.

It also seems like this would allow criminals to recognize him, which wouldn't end up well.

He plans on killing every criminal he meets, so he wouldn't really have any need to make them recognize him like Batman would.

Comment: Because disguises/masks are for gutless wimps

Comment: He doesn't need to protect his loved ones, he is who he is because of their deaths.

Comment: @Politank-Z He does have a bunch of allies, though. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Punisher_characters#Allies)

Comment: He has a [Grenade Machine Gun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_grenade_launcher).  People who have those don't need disguises.

Comment: Not actually sure he's technically a superhero.

Comment: @Richard - because he is a schmuck (tm)

Comment: What are they going to do? Send him to prison?... I want to read that comic.

Comment: How many live to identify him

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Because he has no "other life"

Spider-man likes to sometimes just be Peter Parker, Superman enjoys writing articles as Clark Kent and you won't tell me that Batman doesn't occasionally enjoys high-life perks of Bruce Wayne. And they all have someone, who could be hurt, if the truth would get out.

And then is Frank Castle - person who lost everything: He has no one or nothing to protect (even other super heroes don't want to work with him!), all he wants is to exact justice on criminals. Why should he hide his face? He wants his victims to know, that it was him, not some masked symbol, that sends them to Hell.

It is also a unspoken challenge to anyone who would like to stop him - "You know who I am, come and get me!".

Comment: "not some masked symbol"- Then why does he make himself known by his skull symbol?

Comment: Because its easier, more cool and more scary than wearing ID tag on his chest.  Please notice that while he wears a symbol he doesn't hide his face, hence its not "masked symbol" like i.e. Batman: he is both "the Punisher" and Frank Castle at the same time. Also in movie adaptation, that shirt was given to him by his son.

Comment: That and he is crazy, after the death of his family

Answer (score 6):

The most recent iteration of [The Punisher](http://www.comicvine.com/the-punisher/4050-71435/) (All New Marvel Now!) does wear a mask.

[image]

The reasoning being that since he was relocated to the West Coast, his face isn't as well known as it was on the East Coast. (As little sense as that makes, what with him being a well known mass murderer.)